# Issues revolving Promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, promise

I am having issues with Promises pending and not resolving in time. When I try to use async to wait for a value, what I end up getting "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." and that's probably because I'm calling this peculiar method I'm trying to use that returns a promise in the render lifecycle method. Well, I tried using .then to retrieve the value but that didn't work either.

I'm going to be laying out a couple of files and explaining the best I can what does what and if there are better ways to do what I am trying to do, suggestions would be wonderful! If it's fixable, even better! Any help is greatly appreciated!

App.js (main app)
Components
- Navigation.js (Navigation bar.)
- MainContent.js(Main content: once you click on a navigation item, everything inside of main content changes)

MainContent.js

```
tabHandler = (tab) => {
//what do I do here? Immediately if I place the async keyword in the definition, the compiler hates me, but if I don't, then I don't get what I want.

    const test = this.props.tabAPICall(tab).then(value => { console.log(value) })
    console.log(test);

    //if(tab === all the different navigation tabs, render stuff differently){
    //as an example:
    // return <Songs />
    //}
    //else 
}

render(){
const { chosenTab } = this.props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>


    <ul.className="main-content">
            {
                chosenTab !== "" ? this.tabHandler(chosenTab) : null
            }
        </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

}

the tabAPICall comes from App.js here:

```
tabAPICall = (tab) => {
    const { token, baseUrl } = this.state;

    fetch(`${baseUrl}/albums`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        return data;
    })
```

chosenTab gets updated at the app level to trigger a re-render which is what I want

Comment: Have you tried with `if(data){console.log(data)}`

Comment: If that is to discern whether or not I'm getting information back from the call, then yeah I've tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set data fetching from API to your component state. And display data in the state:

in the tabHandler, after we get the data, set it to this.state.song through setState({ song: value }). When the data in state in changed. React will do the re-render and inject new data in state to your component.

```
constructor() {
   this.state = { song: null }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.tabHandler(this.props.chosenTab)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.chosenTab != this.props.chosenTab) {
        this.tabHandler(nextProps.chosenTab)
    }
}

tabHandler = (tab) => {
//what do I do here? Immediately if I place the async keyword in the definition, the compiler hates me, but if I don't, then I don't get what I want.

    this.props.tabAPICall(tab).then(value => { this.setState({ song: value }) })
}

render(){
    const { chosenTab } = this.props;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>


    <ul.className="main-content">
            { this.state.song ? <Song someProp={song} /> : null }
        </ul>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: So I've actually tried that before and that brings me into an infinite re-render probably because of how the rest of my code is set up

Comment: I doubled back and see what you were trying to do, but having tabHandler called on componentDidMount only triggers once whereas I need the tabHandler to trigger every single time a navigation item is clicked

Comment: You can add componentWillReceiveProps to handle that. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Okay cool, that's sweet but I'm getting the same issue where the API call is returning a pending promise

Comment: I got it to work with some tinkering but the big bulk of this code is correct. Thanks!